# Different ways to factor

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, factoring

I'm interested to know some different methods to factor equations of the form $ax^2+bx+c$, where $a \ne 0$, other than pure guess and check.

Comment: British Method is one way

Comment: What? Please explain

Comment: @fleablood I only know how to use the binomial theorem to expand binomials

Comment: Compute the roots $x_0$ and $x_1$  (poss.ibly equal) with the quadratic formula and factor as $a(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$.

Comment: Other than the method I posted, there's completing the square the the quadratic formula, as others have commented on

Comment: Seriously?  You know that people are asked to factor $ax^2 + bx + c$ but you've never heard of completing the square or the quadratic formula?

Comment: @fleablood Didn't you say the binomial theorem earlier? What do you mean?

Comment: Should different methods be in different answers or added on to the same answer?

Comment: @suomynonA I don't know, either way is fine I guess

Comment: I did say the binomial theorem before.  It was a slip of the tongue.  I meant the quadratic formula.  Seriously.  Did you not know that $ax^2 + bx + c = q(x-r)(x-t) \iff $ r and t are roots $\iff r,t = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$?

Comment: I did; I probably should have mentioned that.

Comment: You didn't mention the domain in which you want to solve. Everyybody seems to assume that you search for solutions in C or R (sorry, don't know the syntax for markup). But if we are in Z/3Z for example, one could just try the different elements...

Comment: I'm talking about real numbers only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One method is The British Method. Here are the steps.

$1)$ Multiply $a*c$.

$2)$ Find a factor pair of $ac$ that adds up to $b$

$3)$ Replace $bx$ in the equation with the two factors, both multiplied by x.

$4)$ Factor by grouping.

Here is an annotated example.
$$2x^2-x-6$$
$$a=2, b=-1, c=-6$$
Here we do step $1$, getting $$ac=-12$$ Then we do step $2$. The factor pair is $$-4,3$$ Now we do step $3$. The equation becomes $$2x^2-4x+3x-6$$
Then we factor by grouping
$$2x^2-4x+3x-6$$ $$2x(x-2)+3(x-2)$$ $$(2x+3)(x-2)$$

---

Another method is shown below.

Steps:

$1)$ Multiply $a*c$.

$2)$ Find a factor pair of $ac$ that adds up to $b$, call them $x_1$ and $x_2$

$3)$ Write the following equation: $(ax+x_1)(ax+x_2)$.

$4)$ Factor out the GCF of each individual equation. The part remaining after factoring out the GCF is your answer.

Annotated example: 
$$2x^2-x-6$$ $$a=2, b=-1, c=-6$$ Here we do step $1$, getting $$ac=-12$$ Then we do step $2$. The factor pair is $$-4,3$$ Now we do step $3$, getting the equation: $$(2x-4)(2x+3)$$ Factor out a $2$ from the first part, where you get the final answer of $$(x-2)(2x+3)$$

Comment: Note though that "find a factor pair of $ac$ that adds up to $b$" really just pushes the "guess and check" into a substep.

Comment: Yes, there is an element of guess and check involved, but OP wrote "pure guess and check" which I interpreted as methods that only used guess and check.

Comment: If we aren't going to use some arithmetic guess and check step then quadratic formula or completing the square become your only options and for many questions those techniques are over the top.

Comment: Updated with another example.

Comment: If were doing arithmetic in our heads: dividing b and c by a, halving the b, squaring, subtracting c from it.  Seeing if that is a perfect square or a rational square. Is almost as easy, eliminates *all* guess work, avoid false starts and dead ends, and allows you not to waste time if there are not answers.

Comment: Thanks for the two methods!

Comment: So $x^2 + 28x + 112$.  Factor 112 to m*n so that m + n = 28 in your head....   good luck with that.  ... or  halve 28 = 14.  Square it is 4*49.  Subtract 112 = 4*49 - 112 = 4*(49 - 28) = 4*21.  Realize it isn't a square so it's not going to factor.  Give up and stop wasting your time.

Comment: @fleablood Chill. I never said these methods were the best methods or the only methods. I'm just giving some interesting methods to answer OP's question.

Comment: Is this how it is generally taught in the UK? It gives me the shivers.

Comment: Thanks again, amazing answer =)

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your question is in earnest and you aren't trolling the answer is

$ax^2 + bx + c = a(x  + \frac{b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a})(x  + \frac{b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} )$

No guessing.  If the equation factors at all (which it won't if $4ac > b^2$) then it will *always* factor to that.

Comment: The OP isn't asking for different factorizations, but for different *methods* of arriving at a factorization.  Certainly when you see $x^2 + 6x - 8$ you don't factor it using the quadratic formula, do you?

Comment: The op said "other than guessing and checking"  I *never* guess.  I solve and factor from that.  If the OP knew how to solve there'd be no reason to ask the question.  No, I personally find completely the square to be easier than the quadratic equation but .. why on earth would you be surprised if I did...  Factoring *is* the same thing as solving.

Comment: I apologize for presuming, but I think most people look at $x^2  + 6x - 8$ and think to themselves "What two numbers multiply to $-8$ and sum to $6$?"

Comment: So ... given $x^2 + 6x - 8$ I'd divide the 6 to get 3 and square it to get 9 subtract 9 from -8 to to get -17.  Switch signs and take the two  square roots and and three to  get $(x - 3+ \sqrt(17))(x - 3 - \sqrt(17))$ ... which *is* the quadratic formula.

Comment: No two rational numbers sum to -8 and sum to 6.  If it wer $x^2 + 6x + 8$ I'd take a look at that but if before I go grubbing and guessing I want to know if there is a potato in that mud.  $x^2 + 6x + 10$ won't have any and though $x^2 + 6 + 8$ will it's just as easy to square 3 and subtract 8 to get 1.  That way I *know* it will factor. $x^2 + 6x + 10$ won't.

Comment: I think my misplaced minus sign really undermined my point.  :(  Then again it's probably about at the same level of error as saying "binomial theorem" for "quadratic formula" so let's say we're even.

Answer (score 8):

Variation of the method mentioned by @suomnonA

1) Multiply $a*c$.

2) Find a factor pair of $ac$ that adds up to $b$. Let them be $x_1$ and $x_2$.

3) Write factors as:

$$\frac{(ax-x_1)(ax-x_2)}{a}$$

The factors on top will factorize down to cancel out with the $a$ on the bottom.

Example:

$$6x^2+17x-14$$
$$a=6, b=17, c=-14$$
Here we do step $1$, getting $$ac=-84$$ Then we do step $2$. The factor pair is $$-4,21$$ Now we do step $3$.

The equation becomes $$\frac{(6x-4)(6x+21)}{2}$$

which factorizes to

$$\frac{2(3x-2)\cdot3(2x+7)}{6}$$

$$(3x-2)(2x+7)$$

Comment: Apparently this is referred to as the Airplane Method.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

$$a\,{{x}^{2}}+bx+c$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$n\,{{x}^{2}}-2knx+{{k}^{2}}n-m$$
$$\downarrow$$
$${{x}^{2}}-2kx-\frac{m}{n}+{{k}^{2}}$$
$$\downarrow$$
$$\left( x-\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}-k\right) \,\left( x+\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}}-k\right) $$