# Biquadratic and quartic polynomial factorisation and squares

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, factoring

Given the polynomial $x^4 +ax^2 +b$ I have to determine if it is reducible or not in $Q$. Firstly it hasn't roots, so the only possibility is a factorization between two polynomial of second degree. 
Being a biquadratic polynomial (I mean a polynomial of fourth degree without the factors of first and third degree) I know that it is equal to $t^2 +at +b$, $t = x^2$ so, found a square ($\alpha$) I know the other ones are $-\alpha , \overline{\alpha}, \overline{-\alpha}$ so I can rewrite the polynomial as $(x-\alpha)(x+\alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})(x+
\overline{\alpha})$. However this factorization is wrong because the squares aren't in $Q$ so I have to combine the squares so as to obtain a factors in $Q$.

> If this method doesn't work (I don't find a combination of square in $Q$) it means that the polynomial is irreducible?

Comment: Are you talking about the general case or this example in particular?

Comment: The general case

Comment: I do not understand this question. There are many ways to factorize a polynomial, but in the end the factorization is always unique. I don't get the "equation system" part as well.

Comment: If the biquadratic factors in $\mathbb Q$, it will as $(x^2-r_1)(x^2-r_2)$ where $r_i\in \mathbb Q$. If one or both the $r_i$ are squares in $\mathbb Q$, then you can factor further into linear terms. Not sure if that’s what you are asking for though.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937742/different-ways-to-factor/1941684#1941684